# Are bugs welcome?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

After more than two years on the Stack Exchange community I learned that bugs are not to be solved *here*, so they don't provide useful content on the sites. They should not be deleted but closed.

Now I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11836232/1505348) that mention an issue that is in fact a bug. After two flags mentioning this, both got rejected. I imagine, by two different mods.

So, my question is, have something changed in this time? Are bugs welcome to be posted as new questions and remain *open*?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "this question that is in fact a bug" A *bug* is a technical error. A question can't be an error. If anything, it appears to be a question asking if a certain behavior in a developer tool is a bug. How is that off-topic? On the other hand, had the question been phrased as if it were a bug report (e.g. expected behavior; actual behavior; steps to reproduce; even a possible patch or a call to action but *not a question*), then it would be off-topic, because we're a Q&A site and not a bug tracker.

Comment: A bug in a program written by an SO user can be off topic, there's leeway if enough programmers make the exact same mistake and the bug behavior is googable.  A bug in a tool that many programmers use is very much on topic, that hurts lots of programmers.  Even "it's a known problem" is a proper answer.

Comment: @BoltClock typo fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant in such a case, we will *reopen closed question* more than leave them open. Because in most cases a new question won't get a lot of attention to say that it hurts lots of programmers.

Comment: I have this problem too. What to do with a question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326849/combining-mediawiki-apiusers-and-apiusercontribs which can't be really solved until the bug is fixed? Accept the bug report link as answer? Close? Let the question rot until the bug is fixed?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303974/are-link-only-answers-pointing-to-resolved-bug-reports-answers , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308817/what-do-i-do-if-a-question-i-asked-turned-out-to-be-a-platform-bug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me that this question should be allowed.

First, we do welcome questions about software development tools. Netbeans is one such development tool, and it is asking about an aspect of it which is relevant to software development.

Second, it is something other people may encounter. This is confirmed by the question score (39 at the time of writing).

Third, it does have a resolution that can be described in an answer. While there is currently no answer that says how to work around it, going to the bug linked in the current answer and following the duplicate link says that it was fixed in some version. If an answer were posted which stated something to the effect of “this is a bug. Upgrade to version something-or-other and it will be fixed,” that is actionable advice that can be taken by anyone who has this problem later.

Comment: So as you and @HansPassant mentioned, the only case where a bug will be on-topic is if it is a "popular bug".

Comment: "Popular bug"...? No I'm pretty sure it doesn't make a difference whether a bug is popular or common, or if it's obscure. It's still a bug.