# Are link-only answers pointing to resolved bug reports answers?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

I am asking about a very narrow exception case here that is not covered by previous questions on this topic.

When an issue someone is having is caused by a **bug in the software library they're using**, and then someone answers: "It's fixed in this version, here's the case number"... it's hard for me to imagine what else they might say.

Should we be holding answers that refer bug reports and fixed versions to users as "not answers", even if they're one sentence? Or should we require a little more?

I should mention that I've seen these sorts of answers get deleted in the LQPQ reasonably often, but since it's much harder to search for deleted answers, I don't have any handy. I'll attempt to look, though.

---

Here are some *recent* examples of ones that look like low quality, but maybe really aren't:

[This answer got immediately upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332691/1768232):

> This is probably fixed by https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3544 on Mojarra.

Then I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32332306/1768232):

> This has been fixed about two week ago in OpenWrt trunk and CC, see this: https://dev.openwrt.org/changeset/46603

And [this self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32329405/1768232):

> This issue was related to parse version and it was fixed in later version

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32317973/1768232)

> There was a bug in which AdParameters resulted empty. It should be fixed. Here's the issue if you want to fix it in your own Kaltura player. https://github.com/kaltura/mwEmbed/pull/2040

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32296189/1768232):

> Seems that for few people it got fixed by updating to Xcode 7 beta 5
>
> https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11909

---

However, in my search I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32328092/1768232), which looks like a much higher quality "link-only" answer:

> Looks like you're the owner of the thread over on GitHub but just in case anyone else gets the error in the meantime, there appears to be a bug in that particular version of Squirrel, whereby it's not closing a zip file it creates, here is the tracked error: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/pull/425 doesn't look like too long until it will be fixed.
>
> Here is the link to the other thread in GitHub also: https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/422

---

This is not a duplicate of [Why was my custom flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302619/why-was-my-custom-flag-declined) because:

1. No flag was declined here, this question is about questions I've seen in the Low Quality posts queue and what to do in these situations
2. The other question has *nothing* to do with bug reports
3. This is a narrow case that so often *incorrectly* makes it into the Low Quality Posts queue that it deserves special attention in its own meta post.

Comment: Just came to search/post this, for the same review you saw (second one in your list, I skipped it). As per the answers, I suppose what else can people answer with, they cannot post an actual bug fix, so link the bug report/fix is fine as long as they have explained as well and not just "see this [link]".

Comment: The fact that you were able to tell that these were links to bug reports because **every single one of them said so** should be a clear indicator that none of these qualify as link-only. (One of them doesn't even *have* a link - I'd consider that unsourced.)

Comment: As for "requiring a little more", what more do you want? The people who patched the bug / closed the issue to show up and document the entire process of how they resolved it? Why should that be a *requirement*?

Comment: @BoltClock that was a question I was asking, not a rhetorical suggestion in disguise. I actually agree with you but I was trying to phrase the post neutrally.

Comment: @BoltClock also, I have seen these posts get deleted by the LQPQ but I wasn't able to find any examples because I can't search deleted posts.

Comment: @durron597: Great, more examples of reviewers who don't know what they're doing.

Comment: @BoltClock well, hopefully this meta question will help that problem a little.

Comment: @TravisJ Those two questions have nothing to do with each other. What does that have to do with bug reports?

Comment: @durron597 - If the answer makes an attempt to answer the question, it is an answer. The sooner you get used to that, the less you will encounter these incidents.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

"*It's fixed in version X*" / "*It's a bug and this is the ticket*" is an answer, and even if short, it's often not actually a bad one.

Though if there's any chance people might not be able to upgrade to the fixed version or it isn't fixed yet, it's not really a *good* answer without a workaround if that's feasible.

Also, if it is added late, adding it as a highly visible update to the existing good answers would be far preferable.

Comment: "Link only" really means *nothing* but the link.  "If you removed the link, would the post (attempt to) answer the question?  If so, it is not link only!"  The ones who state the version the fix is in are good answers.  The ones that just say "it was a bug, link" are on the edge of being bad answers.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sorry, didn't know, however I've learned now a new abbreviation ([iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if)).

Answer (score 18):

A definitive fix, with a link to a resolved Github issue is fine in my mind. It says `If you're using version X, and you're having this problem, then upgrade to version Y.` It helps the original user, and it points any future visitors to a potential fix and further information. There isn't a whole lot more, in my mind, that can be nor needs to be said.

Answers such as `it might be fixed if you upgrade` or `it's probably fixed in version Y` should be dealt with. They aren't confirmed solutions and are basically a form of shotgun debugging.

Comment: Agree, using non-commited words such as "it might be...", "it's probably...", "try this...", etc, without any definitive answer provided, belong in comments. Sometimes I'll test what the "answer" says and if it's correct, edit the answer to remove any words of doubt. Otherwise the answer should be resigned to a comment or deleted.

Comment: If only a comment could be excepted as the correct answer by the question author....

Answer (score 4):

Most questions asked on Stack Overflow are based on the user actually having a programming error or lack of knowledge on the programming / software they are using and as such we expect both the questions and answers to be a bit more informative and detailed.

But, when the issue is not related to the poster's efforts or knowledge and is in fact a known ***bug*** of the language/software version then adding an extra paragraph of information just to arrive at the same point "it's a known bug, here's the patch/bug report link" doesn't add in more value to the answer than just the link did.

In these cases, I don't see where an extended answer adds anymore value than the short links / explanations do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at one time I asked a question which was caused by a bug, I didn't know it was a bug at the time, provided what was the workaround we found as self answer. Sometime later (about 6-8 weeks) the bug was fixed. I edited the answer indicating the version which was fixed. It was all good for a while, until I discovered that my question was getting in the way of people that was looking for other problems no related to my issue.

What I did was deleting the whole Q&A. **The original issue was effectively unreproducible**, and the question was being unhelpful rather than helpful later on. So having a Q&A pair about bugs isn't actually helpful in the long term, especially if the bug isn't reported (mine was after a week I discovered) due people using a workaround. So, if you see an already fixed bug, which was fixed by upstream and isn't relevant for most purposes, close and delete the **question**.

Comment: That's sure a good idea, iff there's no chance anyone is stuck with the unfixed version.