# Should I close my question if I've upgraded the problem scenario away?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question where I have outlined a very specific communication scenario between two systems using two specific versions of software (the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870398/why-are-spyjmsexceptions-still-thrown-after-recycling-the-client-jboss-connectio); no arbitrary voting, please).

One of the systems has been upgraded to a much higher version, and it solved the problem; I can no longer test any proper answers (not that there were ever any) against the scenario.

Should I answer and close out my question, or should I leave it open?

I suppose I should post an answer about how upgrading the lesser server solved the problem, which then leaves it as an answered question on the site, just with a lesser answer, never to be solved unless someone recreates the scenario.  Yes?

**Edit:** Of note, I've now answered the question with the upgrade statement, even though it does not identify and solve the ultimate underlying cause.  Should I have done this?

Comment: If upgrading solved the issue, then it _is_ a solution, at least for those who can upgrade. Sounds right as an answer to me. It's definitely good, in my mind, that you did post the answer for future visitors.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303974/792066

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The relevant close reason reads:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be
>   reproduced** or **a simple typographical error.** While similar
>   questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner
>   unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by
>   identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to
>   reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

The key phrase here is *"was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers".* *That* is the root cause for closing such questions.

So, your problem indeed can no longer be reproduced. But was it "resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers"? It wasn't! Your answer is *a* way to solve the problem, so it *is* a help for future readers. Of course, it might not be *the* help they want, but no-one makes such commitments to them.

So, your answer is not a "definitive", "exhaustive" answer, but it is quite valid *an* answer, and will justfully be outvoted by an exhaustive one if it's ever posted.

Is it worthy of being accepted? [Acceptance means](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work):

> The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to
>   be the most helpful to you, personally.

Does this one qualify? Well, since it's the *only* answer that "was helpful to you, personally"...

Another corollary is: *you are under no obligation to keep monitoring the question indefinitely for better answers.* Because if you don't, a new answer won't "help you, personally".