# Should this answer deleted as link-only be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, specific-answer

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24013793/38765 was deleted with the comment

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

The answer is currently

> This pull request to progress_bar fixed the progress bar error. Upgrade your version of progress_bar to a version including this patch. https://github.com/paul/progress_bar/pull/22

I don't think in its current state it is a link-only answer. It's not a link to a source of information that should be summarized in this answer, but a link to a pull request that fixes the problem the OP had, plus a description of that link.

Should it be undeleted? ([Related discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303974/are-link-only-answers-pointing-to-resolved-bug-reports-answers))

I've previously voted for undeletion, and I tried flagging it for undeletion, but the flag has been pending for a week, and I assume it's not going to get resolved without the meta effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has since been undeleted. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)