# Is it link-only when there is a link and description but no code?

Tags: discussion, answers, link-only-answers, code

As one of your newest moderators, I've been handling a bunch of not-an-answer flags.  One NAA flag was for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997481):

[image]

The flag comment said that the link was broken.  When reviewing the flag, I:

1. Confirmed that the link was broken
2. Decided that without the link markup, "In MySQL, you can create a limited user (create new user and grant limited access), which can only access certain table." would be an attempt to answer the question.
3. Found a new link and edited it into the answer.
4. Marked the flag as helpful without deleting the answer.

However, the flagger commented:

> It's still just a link-only answer. Answers should contain the relevant code. If the link is removed, this is just a comment. It says right in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - Provide context for links implies that (e.g. code is the relevant part).

Is code required here for this to be considered more than a link-only answer?

I think this case is more similar to [Should this answer deleted as link-only be undeleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325803/should-this-answer-deleted-as-link-only-be-undeleted) where the description (but no code) was enough to get the answer un-deleted.  And less similar than to [Link-and-link-description-only answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305472/link-and-link-description-only-answer) where the "description" with the link was all filler.

Comment: I will also point out, after looking at 100s of LO - NAA flags, there is some inconsistency in the way the LO - NAA flags are handled in general. I don't mean just by @StephenOsermiller, but by the community in general. So being a person who flags a lot of this type of answer, it's not always clear.

Comment: Your NAA flags tend to be harder to deal with than average.  Most NAA flags are for "thx" and "me too" answers.  Your flags are mostly for link-only where the link has varying levels of description around it.

Comment: That's probably true. I try to curate the quality of SO answers relevant to my python experience, so I may flag LQA / NAA on the harder side of the relevant meta documentation. I have a [script](https://github.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/blob/master/Tools/SO_Linkonly_Parser.py) for finding such answers, then manually evaluate them.

Comment: I have a lot of "helpful" LQA / NAA, and even given the relevant meta posts for guidance, I don't always get it right.

Comment: [This answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF0wt.png) was deleted as LO - NAA, and I don't really see how it's much different than the answer under discussion.

Comment: I'd say that that answer is worse, @TrentonMcKinney ; it's more saying "Write the solution yourself, or use an existing tool". The answer here, however, is saying that such a feature within the product exists, and tells you what that feature is called; what it lacks is an explanation of *how* to implement said feature.

Comment: @ThomA even though the question does not specifically say it's for MySQL? The question text states SQL, and is given [tag:sql]. The question is not clear about the server.

Comment: Yes, @TrentonMcKinney .

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I replaced the link you had added with one which is more equivalent to the old one. I've checked the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150108042436/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) and the one I've linked now should be a better match.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney You are abusing NAA flag. You shouldn't use them to make moderators do the work, you could. If the link has gone bad, you can find the replacement. Plenty of those answers stand on their own without the link. Also if there is a closed question that is of no value, you can vote to delete it and you can go to SOCVR to ask for assistance in deleting. Flagging every answer there as NAA is not the way to do cleanup.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Also if you are going to mass digging through 14 years old answers, then you can at least put some effort and write appropriate comments, if you really feel they are needed, instead of canned ones that tell 20K+ users that when and if they get sufficient reputation they will be able to post comments.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar _you can go to SOCVR to ask for assistance in deleting_ I didn’t have previous knowledge of SOCVR, but I just looked it up.

Comment: I once flagged an answer that read: "Use a <link>number table</link>", where the "number table" was a link detailing how to create number tables. It was rejected, as it contained the very minimum of what is considered an answer apparently. I didn't agree then, still on the fence now, but I've resigned to it. Basically, it put the notion "number table" in the mind of the questioner, which they could then further research.

Comment: (Most of the Stack Overflow jargon is covered by [the glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms). [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/). Though not "LQA" and "LO". [SIAs](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=SIA)?)

Comment: *LO* is probably *link-only*.

Comment: What is *LQA*?... Low-quality answer?

Answer (score 49):

No, code isn't required, but the answer does need to at least have enough information that the answer can be used without following the link. I don't believe code must exist for that to be the case.

I think this one is probably fine, given the question isn't how to create a limited user, and thus the answer doesn't need to demonstrate that part directly.

---

Put another way, the link isn't a necessary part of this answer. It can be removed and the answer would still be an answer.

Comment: To me "In MySQL, you can create a limited user (create new user and grant limited access), which can only access certain table." seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It probably could exist as just a comment, yes.  Many comments could be answers, and many answers could be comments. That an answer could exist as a comment doesn't make it not an answer..

Comment: It certainly doesn't make it link only, in any case.

Comment: In the most rigid interpretation, it doesn’t qualify as LO due to the presence of extra text, even though LO is merely a part of NAA. It certainly appears to be either VLQ or NAA. If you’re not utilizing MySQL, and the question doesn’t specify this, and you’re unaware of what a limited user implies, then that response is NAA.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney that answer is not VLQ at all, see: [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag) It is also not NAA since it basically says "Create a new user and grant it limited access" which is an answer to "How can I allow users to run arbitrary SQL safely?" Does it lack explanation on how to create the user and grant it permissions? Yes. Does that disqualify it as an answer? No.

Comment: To be honest, I disagree with the sentiment on this particular answer being a comment. The comment box specifically says "Avoid answering questions in comments", and this is clearly an attempt at an answer. Frankly, it's a half decent answer. It would be better with the SQL code showing you what to do, but the OP doesn't actually specify what version of SQL they're using, so it's possible the code can change. But the answer gives instructions: create a user and then grant them only access to a certain table...

Comment: ...A DBA would probably understand how to do this, the question asked what to do, and the answer addresses that. I would be fine with people not liking the answer and downvoting, but I find people way more often answer questions in comments than write comments as answers, and it seriously is bad practice. I've missed a LOT of helpful answers for a long time because they were buried as comments on the question, and I only look at the answers.

Answer (score 19):

Without code it's an *incomplete* answer. I would personally downvote it because it doesn't answer the question without the link—the person who asked the question presumably doesn't know about limited users (I certainly don't), so this answer is basically telling me the correct Google search terms. Might as well leave an "let me google that for you" link.

Is it an answer? Yes.

Is it a good one? No.

Downvote and move on.

Answer (score 16):

I don't think you can rely on a simple rule that applies the same in all cases where this happens; often the description of the link is *not* enough information to qualify. However, in this specific case, I think the description is enough to qualify it as an OK, attempt at answering.