# What to do with a question which has no solution for the "asker"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, unanswered-questions

[I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136918/objective-c-fabsf-wrong-result-type) some time ago now. I was trying to understand what I was not understanding of an interface, and in the comments came out it was (likely) a bug in the interface itself.

I opened a ticket in their (Apple in this case) bug tracker, and after a year the ticket is still not even considered.

It was a minor issue, but I wonder:

*What is best to do with the question: should I leave it unanswered, or shortly answer myself "it's likely a framework bug or whatever"?*

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303976/4751173).

Comment: well, the question isn't answered yet, and can only be answered by the developers, so... it isn't necessarily off topic, too broad, or unclear, it's just unanswerable until the bug is fixed. Not necessarily a bad thing, it's acting as a sign-post sending users to the appropriate bug report.

Comment: Nice hint @Glorfindel , searched for something similar for a while.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, sadly the bug reports are private at Apple -.-

Comment: You can dupe your Radar at https://openradar.appspot.com/ to make it public.

Comment: Thanks @JoshCaswell, nice to know

Comment: [I've had something similar happening to me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111624/golang-stdin-reads-german-umlauts-wrong), I did answer myself, explained what I knew about the bug (and hopefully help others who may have a similar problem) and added a link to the issue.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think it would be okay to add a self answer stating that the issue in the question appears to be a bug and then link to the bug report so future visitors can see it.  This way people who hit this same issue at least see that there is a problem, it is just not solved as it is a bug.  I really dislike having that as just a comment as comment as for clarification and confirming it is a bug is more an answer to me.

Once/if it is ever fixed the answer can be updated to include the fix information.

Comment: But he doesn't know that it's a bug.  He just suspects that it's a bug, but hasn't heard back from the developers yet.  If the developer's had *confirmed* that it was a bug (or an answerer could prove that it was), then that would be an answer.

Comment: @Servy I would still add it as an answer until it is proven wrong.  If someone comes along and post an answer that proves it is not a bug then the bug report answer can be removed.

Comment: Saying, "I assume it's a bug in the framework" without any basis to support that assertion is an awful answer.  An assertion like that needs a lot to back it up.

Comment: Seems like the issue is not present anymore in the last version. I guess i will answer declaring it fixed. I wait for some more opinions before to accept your answer anyway, it's an interesting topic.

Comment: @Servy i agree it's a way too free assertion, a wrong or undocumented behaviour was anyway present and witness by others in the comments. The question stays open if not for this particular in general cases anyway, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted my own question because it not only became useless for me, it was a bug, was properly fixed by the maker *and* was getting in the way of people looking for information about the error but that didn't have the same causes. So, yeah, if you find that your question is no longer useful, you can delete it.