# Should we have a 'Not an answer because a bug was found' label for questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, close-reasons

Scrolling through the Unanswered questions lists, it is very common to find a discussion on the comment section that ends up with a link to the official report of a bug (Exhibit A: [Unanswered because bug found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693601/removing-unused-categories-in-series-results-in-duplicated-categories))

Since this seems to be a quite common occurrence in the unanswered subset (particularly for Python 3.x) maybe there's value in closing questions with a "Bug" flag.

Is there such a feature already? If not, does it make sense to have one?

Comment: Not passive aggresive, I would like some feedback on the down votes please

Comment: Why, no. The answer to that could still be "This is due to a bug, reported _here_. A workaround is ...".

Comment: Downvotes on Meta mean disagreement.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: A quick template for an answer could be _This is a (un)confirmed bug in version <number>, and has not been fixed/fixed in version <number>. Workarounds are <unavailable/list of workaround>_. Such answers are generally considered valuable

Comment: Also, a question isnt closed simply because it doesnt have an answer.. It is closed if it is not possible to answer it in the current state

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I totally agree, I'm stealing your template

Comment: Very similar question, possibly a duplicate: [What to do with a question which has no solution for the "asker"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336966/7795130)

Comment: @DavyM I would same that indeed it is the same question. Thank you for noticing

Comment: Related: [What to do with question where the answer are confirmed and fixed bugs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369618/4639281)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Saying that a bug was found *is* an answer to the question.  It doesn't mean that it's not an answer in the slightest.

Answer (score 8):

I would advise against it: until the bug gets fixed, their problem is still open.

If you want to get them out of the Unanswered tab, I would suggest answering with *workarounds*.