# Should I delete a question of mine which I feel is no longer relevant?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

A couple of years ago I asked question about getting version X of foo to work with version Y of bar. It got some upvoted answers (my own question is at 0 votes). These days, both X and Y are not the current versions; and the answer would be "just upgrade".

I'm not sure my question still has any value to readers. Should I delete it?

Comment: You can't delete it since it has upvoted answers. Also: don't assume that simply because there are newer versions everybody can upgrade... For good or bad there's plenty of cases with people stuck with a certain version of a software for good or bad reasons, as such almost no question can ever become "obsolete" (there have been questions about *decades* old hardware and software before).

Comment: @Bakuriu: If you make that an answer I guess I'll accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You *can't* delete your question since it has upvoted answers. If you really want to delete it you can flag it for moderation attention with a custom flag and explain to the moderator that you want the question to be deleted, why you can't do that by your own and *a very good reason for this to happen*.

However, I believe that your reasoning is wrong. Questions *almost never* become obsolete. There's plenty of people that for some reason are stick with old versions of software and are unable to upgrade, as such just because there exists newer versions of software that fix a problem doesn't mean that a question explaining how to fix that problem with older versions is useless.

It may be useful to edit the answer or question specifying that a new version of the software exists and that fixes the problem described.

Comment: This is inaccurate, the user can delete his question, just that it would need 2 other users to agree with the deletion, and that it is closed first.

Comment: @Braiam You forgot that you also need a negative score for other users to be able to vote for deletion...

Comment: No, anyone can vote to delete a positive scored question.

Comment: @Braiam No you can't. [Try it on this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332001/is-it-possible-to-hide-notice-for-a-particular-line-in-php-by-writing-some-code) there is no "delete" option for the question. You can *flag* the question but that is **not** the same as voting for deletion.  In contrast [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332310/how-do-facebook-run-their-code) has the "delete" option because it has a score of -3.

Comment: [Read the tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/vote-to-delete/info): allow them to cast delete votes on questions which have been **closed for at least two days**. The one you are talking about is the 20k privilege. Anyone with 10k can vote to delete [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/549/792066) for example

Comment: I have to violently disagree with your rationale. Pouring effort into helping people stay on outdated, unsupported, and insecure libraries, is a huge disservice to our industry.

Comment: @Drenmi Good luck getting certain industries(like banking) to upgrade to the latest and greatest version of whatever software they run. Sometimes you have to work with what you have, not what you *should* have.

Comment: @BoogaRoo those are the exception, not the rule. If they want to stay on obsolete software, that's their prerogative, but the rest of the world deserves better.

Comment: @BoogaRoo Of course some will cling to outdated practices. I'm just saying I won't be part of the problem by spending energy on making it easier for them to do so. An important part about being a professional is defending our objectives (within reason, of course.)

Comment: @Drenmi In anycase you have to consider that SO is **not** only about "the industry". For example: what if I found a piece of old hardware in my garage, which only runs the old versions of said softwares? I believe asking about making it work is a perfectly fine question on SO. Moreover, nobody here said that the old versions are "unsupported", that's completely your own assumption... for the matter at hand the "old version of software X" could simply be python2.7...

Comment: @Bakuriu: Yes. This might be the way SO wants to go, but just because I understand that doesn't mean I need to agree. :-) Sorry. Should've been "outdated, unsupported, *or* insecure versions".

Answer (score 8):

If the correct answer is now "just upgrade", then post that as an answer, along with an explanation of why this is *now* the correct answer.

Comment: I absolutely agree with this. If anybody is still facing the problem with the old version it is useful for them to know whether it has been fixed. That could even be a contributing factor to the decision about when to upgrade. And for anybody using the newest version it may be useful for them to know that the problem is supposed to have been fixed.

Comment: What happens if I'm using the latest version and the problem persists ?

Comment: @Braiam well if that happens, then you could post a comment to that effect under the answer that I'm suggesting the OP could post.  If the OP doesn't post this answer, then you'd have to raise a new question (which might just get closed as a dupe).

Comment: NO, I would downvote the post, since the answer is not helpful and/or the question for misleading me into a unhelpuf answer. Fomenting people to post new questions instead of dealing with the vendor is a waste of moderating time that can be well used elsewhere. I prefer deletion. People will find the bug trackers with status updates and contact with the developers.

Comment: Well, hopefully the people who DID find the answer useful would upvote it.

Comment: @Braiam Not sure why you bothered phrasing your comment as a question if you had already decided on an answer. Anyway, if an answer is wrong and it's not actually fixed, sure, downvote. Whoever posts the answer indicating that an upgrade fixes it should have tested that before posting, though, so unless I could definitively show that the *same problems* still occur with the versions they recommend, I would assume I'm facing a new problem that is probably specific to my situation. That would be more of a reason to post a new question (detailing differences) than to downvote their answer.

Comment: @jpmc26 I was expecting a novel solution that I didn't consider. What I have is yet another catch 22: the question doesn't solve your problem, nor you can ask anew without drama.

Comment: @Braiam If you do a sufficient job explaining why your question is not a duplicate before you post it, why would there be any "drama"?

Comment: @jpmc26 why *you* don't expect drama?

Comment: @jpmc26 There often is "drama".  As a general rule, users of Stack Overflow are far too eager to close questions as duplicates.  Often questions are closed as duplicates when they REALLY aren't - and it's awfully difficult to get them re-opened.  Explaining "this is not a duplicate of X because ..." usually doesn't help - now that you've found X, it makes it easier for the "eager to close" brigade, and it will get closed as a duplicate even more quickly than if you hadn't included the explanation.

Comment: @Braiam If you feel that none of the answers to an existing question are "correct", you can always post a bounty on the question, instead of creating a new, very similar question.

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't know what you're talking about. I see questions all the time that I'm about 95% sure the concepts are covered in previous questions and never get closed period, despite being terrible questions. The few cries of, "It's not a duplicate," I see usually stem from the poster not understanding the concepts enough to figure out how the other answer applies to them.

Comment: @jpmc26 Then your experience differs from mine.

Comment: @Braiam Because most of the drama I see comes from the people who ask ill posed questions or generally don't know what they're talking about. If you have a genuinely different problem, you can produce a different error message, document how you tried the other solution and it didn't help (as part an MVCE), or word your question differently enough that it barely even looks like the other one. Most of the time, you can even do this up front before posting. If the asker is arguing with readers instead of **editing**, that's on them, and there's no need to engage in debate with them.

Answer (score -2):

Is your question getting in the way of people that was looking for other problems no related to the issue? I would delete it, as [I did with mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311495/792066) since the issue was effectively unreproducible. That can get you a sane rule of thumb.

Comment: Not that I know of. It title is essentially "how to get foo X to work with bar Y?" Of course, terms in the answers or the question could come up in searches on other subjects.

Comment: @einpoklum well, next issue is: it's easily reproducible/can trip up the unaware? ie. can people reproduce it, without going out of their way to find themselves into the same situation? Like deliberately using an old version which is buried in the download page.

Comment: I think my last comment actually answers that. They would need to want to use older versions X and Y for some reason.