# Clarification regarding specific First Post question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62893083/1456253) while going through the first posts queue. I skipped it because, while it felt wrong to me, I didn't know exactly how to respond.

The OP is trying to embed an excel document into sharepoint. Specifically they're having trouble getting the scrollbars to show up.

One of the answers indicates that this is a bug (but fails to give a version number or link to the tracker as indicated in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303974/are-link-only-answers-pointing-to-resolved-bug-reports-answers)).

My first instinct was to flag this as not an answer, since the majority of the response was basically pleasantry. After stripping that away you're left with one actually helpful statement:

> This bug is now fixed

There are two pieces of information here: One, that this behavior is a bug, and two, that in new versions of the software it should be fixed. That is actually useful information. Now I start to second guess myself. According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1456253), benefit of the doubt goes to the answer. If there was an attempt, it counts. So perhaps a downvote for lack of specifics rather than a flag, or a comment asking for clarification?

Comment: Rotem Eisenkot works in the Excel team, https://bascatalog2019.azurewebsites.net/SpeakerDetail.aspx?id=540028

Comment: *One, that this behavior is a bug, and two, that in new versions of the software it should be fixed. That is actually useful information.* That's enough. The poster clearly isn't that experienced with SO, but it looks like a valid answer. It could deserve a bit of elaboration, though. If it were me, coming across that in review, I might (1) edit out the "Thanks..." noise, and (2) comment asking for *which* version specifically the bug is now fixed, so that it's more useful for others.

Comment: @CertainPerformance And yet, the answer was deleted by a mod! FWIW, I do agree that it's a useful answer.

Comment: @41686d6564 I've pinged, hopefully he can come and contribute to the discussion

Comment: I would consider it an important piece of information whether the answer actually says which versions of the software contain the fix.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This post doesn't warrant a flag. It is neither "not an answer", because it answers the issue by telling that it shouldn't occur anymore when using the newest version, nor is it "very low quality", because that flag is for "gibberish" answers.

If you want to downvote the answer, that is up to you, but you're welcome to write a comment and explain the issues on the post, like the missing information or the unneeded "thank you for reporting the issue" part. You're also free to edit out the unimportant content, via edit suggestion (use the "edit" link under the answer post).