# What do I do if a question I asked turned out to be a platform bug?

Tags: discussion, answers, close-reasons, asking-questions

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307621/parse-pointer-permissions-dont-allow-create) which turned out to be a bug in the platform I was using. What should my next course of action be? I think it should still be discoverable for other people who have the same issue, so I do not want to delete it.

Do I answer my own question and update the answer when the bug is fixed, or leave a comment, or edit the question, or close it or what?

Comment: If you have a link to an issue tracker or something like that add it to your answer so users can track it themselves. If you know what version(s) it's broken for, add "this bug affects version 1.5*", and when you know it's fixed add "fixed in version 1.5.4". This way if someone encounters this bug in the future, they'll know immediately whether they're affected and how to resolve it (i.e. upgrade.)

Comment: What's the worst that can happen, if you leave it as is?  That said, I like Dave's comment above me - best bet is to point users to the issue tracker. Then you probably can let things run their course. Eventually, if this platform bug gets resolved I"m guessing the post can be gracefully closed with some custom msg "Platform bug with XYZ has been resolved, so this is obsolete" or something to that effect

Comment: Related: [Are link-only answers pointing to resolved bug reports answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303974/are-link-only-answers-pointing-to-resolved-bug-reports-answers)

Comment: If the answer is "the platform has a bug" that's still helpful information to other users.

Comment: In that case you should feel very lucky not to get a load of down votes.

Comment: Not only an answer like the one Dave is suggesting can very useful to other users, but on some platforms, it can be very useful to you since the more people star (or track) a bug on an official bug tracker, the more it becomes a priority to fix by the people responsible for maintaining that platform.

Comment: Why would you delete it? If you found the answer to the question, _answer it_. This is obvious.

Comment: Been there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12414582/241291.  Done that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6720046/241291.  Still alive.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I considered deleting it because it would presumably be fixed soon and impossible to run into again–but you're right, doesn't make sense to delete it _yet_.

Answer (score 65):

1. Answer the question indicating the issue and any possible
   workaround(if you have one).
2. Alert the proper authorities to fix the bug
3. Once the bug is fixed, you can update the answer to let folks know that it has been fixed in version x.y.z if there's a possibility of older versions still being used. If there's for some reason no chance of it being an issue for someone after it's fixed then delete it if you want or just leave it be.

On my awesome internet connection, the post finally loaded for me after I finished this answer. It seems you've done 1 and 2. So, go have a coffee until it is fixed.

Comment: Can I join?  Approved !

Comment: Could be a long coffee.

Comment: +1, but I'd also add another sub-point: If the vendor and/or "proper authorities" have a public bug tracker then raise the issue there and link to it from your answer so that others can follow progress. (@adamdport has already done this in their answer to the linked question.)

Comment: @LukeH good point. Feel free to edit :P

Comment: What I would add here: Make sure to mention the full version of the software you are using since bugs can be much more version-depending than other problems.

Comment: Also, add relevant details to your question if you haven't already: i.e. I'm having problem x *on platform y*

Comment: [Been there](http://imgur.com/9ou6KL7) @LightnessRacesinOrbit...